# GATE: In ANNIE, Extracting named entities after running Pronominal Coreference module

Tags: java, nlp, named-entity-recognition, gate

**Summary:**
From the GATE site there is this example. http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/jape-repository/coordinated-annotations.html#section-3.

This rule references a result that only occurs after running the co-reference module. Is there a way to extract the entity without running the NE transducer again after the co-reference module?

**My specific problem:**
Currently I have a rule that extracts a noun phrase which I mark with an "Object" annotation. This rule doesn't match phrases that end on pronouns so it doesn't match "it". However, I am trying to using the Pronominal Coreference module in ANNIE to link instances of "it" to other "Object"s that it maybe coreferencing.

The problem is that since my "Object" annotation doesn't match instances of "it", my other rules which use the "Object" annotation won't match sentences where the noun phrase is the word "it" but it is really referencing another "Object". So in actuality, my rule should match this sentence.

This is solved if I run the NE transducer again after the Pronominal Coreference module, but of course this would be expensive and redundant.

Is there a better way to do this?  The obvious thing would be to alter my rules to match instances of "it" but if there is a better way, I'd like to try that.